# What is it that's really decentralized in DEX-es?

Tags: decentralization, decentralized-exchange

The website of a DEX is, and has to be, hosted and run as a normal centralized website Right?

What is it then what's decentralized about DEX-es? Is it **only** the fact that **action** of exchanging coins happens without a third-party, in a decentralized manner, that is?

The question is all DEX-es in general, and on other blockchains too.

Comment: Basically yes, but it sounds like you did not think high of it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, everything but the website is decentralized.

Using Uniswap as an example since it the most known.

You can call Uniswap contracts directly: [Uniswap v3 addresses](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/deploys.md).

https://docs.uniswap.org have examples of [Creating a Trade](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/guides/creating-a-trade), creating a pool, adding and removing liquidity, etc.

Any account can use Uniswap at any time, without being blocked or censored.

Any tokens or pools can be listed on Uniswap.

Anyone can build an alternative frontend to Uniswap without risk of APIs breaking.

Yes, no one takes custody of assets being traded on the DEX.

Comment: Uniswap has some **backend**,  which a user can't see, right? Is there anything that happens there that's hidden from the eye of the user? Some calculations, preparations, utilizing some secrets or private keys, signing data.... ? Or is  **everything** about Uniswap complitely transparent and can be found on blockchain and seen by anyone?

Comment: The website has a backend that gives you the HTML and Javascript, which could be bad. But the website is just a skin on the smart contracts. You can query the contracts directly and examine their code, or use an explorer like https://etherscan.io/address/0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564#code